# Failed to add MvvmCross 6.0.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, mvvmcross

I am trying to upgrade MvvmCross from version 5.x.x to 6.0.0.  My core project updated fine but having problems updating my Android project.  I am getting the following error:

```
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   51.79 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0'
Retrieving package 'MvvmCross 6.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
For adding package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' to project 'Listing.Mobile.Droid' that targets 'monoandroid81'.
For adding package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' to project 'Listing.Mobile.Droid' that targets 'monoandroid81'.
Adding package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' to folder 'C:\VSProjects\Listing\packages'
Added package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' to folder 'C:\VSProjects\Listing\packages'
Added package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' to folder 'C:\VSProjects\Listing\packages' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'MvvmCross.6.0.0' does not exist in project 'Listing.Mobile.Droid'
Executing nuget actions took 2.66 sec
Failed to add reference to 'MvvmCross'.
  Reference unavailable.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.0575672
========== Finished ==========
```

I am not sure if this a NuGet problem, MvvmCross problem or something else.  I have removed all references to MvvmCross 5.x.x to no avail.  I have removed the contents of my **packages** folder and still nothing.  Did anybody run into this issue?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using VS2017.  I eliminated the problem by deleting. project.json.lock.  It might have been a left-over from when I converted the project from VS2015 to VS2017 project setup.  Once removed, I was able to add references for all require MvvmCross packages.

Answer (score 1):

your project targeting .framework 4.5 , if you want use 6.0.0 you have to create cross-platform solution targeting .net standard 1.0 and above